# PyQGIS: How to find features <within> another feature

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, spatial-query

Using a spatial query in QGIS Desktop to select features of layer MTA_ACQ_TE_polygon that are within features of layer nts_snrc_50k works, but I am attempting to do this programatically in PyQGIS, with no luck.

[image: Screen shot of QGIS Desktop]

And this is my attempt:

```
from qgis.core import *

app=QgsApplication([], False)
app.setPrefixPath("C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis", True)
app.initQgis()

mapsheet = QgsVectorLayer("E:/MTOdata/archives/0/MTA_ACQ_TE/nts_snrc_50k.shp", \
    "mapsheet", "ogr")
tenures = QgsVectorLayer("E:/MTOdata/archives/0/MTA_ACQ_TE/MTA_ACQ_TE_polygon.shp", \
    "tenures", "ogr")

if not mapsheet.isValid() or not tenures.isValid():
    print("failed to open shapefiles")
    exit(0)

print("-> loaded mapsheet (%s), tenures (%s)" % (mapsheet.crs().authid(), tenures.crs().authid()))
print("-> finding mapsheet")

for m in mapsheet.getFeatures():
    if m["NTS_SNRC"] == "094E06":
        print("\tfound it!")
        sheet = m.geometry()
        break

print("-> finding claims within")

for t in tenures.getFeatures():
    tenure = t.geometry()
    if tenure.within(sheet):
        print("\tgot one: %s" % t["OBJECTID"])

print("-> done")
```

Which provides the output:

```
-> loaded mapsheet (EPSG:4140), tenures (EPSG:3005)
-> finding mapsheet
        found it!
-> finding claims within
-> done
```

It fails to find any features of MTA_ACQ_TE_polygon within nts_snrc_50k.  Why?

Comment: Have you tried `contains()` instead of `within()` (you'll have to switch `tenure` and `sheet`)?

Comment: Yes I have tried variants of contains, within and even intersect in an effort to debug.

Comment: And have you tried to reproject one of the layers into the same CRS as the other?

Answer (score 2):

I followed ArMoraer's advice, and have reprojected each instance of tenure geometry to match the projection of nts_snrc_50k.

The code looks like this:

```
alb_crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(3005, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.EpsgCrsId)
longlat_crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(4140, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.EpsgCrsId)
tr = QgsCoordinateTransform(alb_crs, longlat_crs)
```

And like this:

```
for t in tenures.getFeatures():
    t.geometry().transform(tr)
    tenure = t.geometry()
    if tenure.within(sheet):
        print("\tgot one: %s" % t["OBJECTID"])
```